# Python: How to restart a thread stopped by flag

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6, python-multithreading

I need to stop/start a thread based on certain conditions. I can use a flag to start it and then stop it, but when I try to start it again I get `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`

As an example, in the following code the user presses the escape key to start or stop the label from flashing. First call starts, second call stops, but third call I get the runtime error.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.label = Label(text="TEXT?", font=('Helvetica', 30))
        self.label.pack()
        self.labelFlash = False
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.flash)
        root.bind("<Escape>", self.flashEvent)
    def flashEvent(self, event):
        if self.labelFlash == False:
            self.labelFlash = True
            self.t.start()
        elif self.labelFlash == True:
            self.labelFlash = False
            print(self.labelFlash)
    def flash(self):
        while self.labelFlash == True:
            self.label.config(bg='red')
            root.update()
            time.sleep(.5)
            self.label.config(bg='green')
            root.update()
            time.sleep(.5)
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How would I restart the thread without getting this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `threading.Event` object to control when the thread calls back into the gui. But calling into the gui outside of the event loop thread is illegal and will eventually cause a crash. Instead, use the `after()` method to schedule a timed event in the loop. This event can change the background color safely and can be cancelled to pause the action.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.flash_colors = ['red', 'green']
        self.cur_color = 0
        self.flash_timer_id = None
        self.label = Label(text="TEXT?", font=('Helvetica', 30))
        self.label.pack()
        root.bind("<Escape>", self.flashEvent)

    def flashEvent(self, event):
        if self.flash_timer_id is None:
            # start flashing
            self.flash()
        else:
            # stop flashing
            self.master.after_cancel(self.flash_timer_id)
            self.flash_timer_id = None

    def flash(self):
        self.label.config(bg=self.flash_colors[
            self.cur_color%len(self.flash_colors)])
        self.cur_color += 1
        root.update()
        # (delay in mS)
        self.flash_timer_id = self.master.after(500, self.flash)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```